# Error 403 on server request xmlrpc

Tags: java, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am using wordpress-java (http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/) to create a test post in my blog but i get an exception:

```
redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: The response could not be parsed.  
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.endCall(Unknown Source)
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.bican.wordpress.$Proxy1.newPost(Unknown Source)
    at net.bican.wordpress.Wordpress.newPost(Wordpress.java:606)
    at Ienmx.<init>(Ienmx.java:39)
    at Pulso.obtenerMinutoAMinuto(Pulso.java:68)
    at principal$1.run(principal.java:24)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:534)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:484)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://pulso.wpengine.com/xmlrpc.php
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1403)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    ... 11 more
```

this is my code:

```
this.w = new Wordpress(usuario, password, xmlUrl);
Page p = new Page();
p.setTitle("Se crea el objeto en el script");
p.setDescription("Este es el cuerpo del post");
try{
    w.newPost(p, true);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

if you go to the url, the url show the classic message:

> XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.

i have no idea of whats wrong :(

Thanks :)

Comment: You might have already checked, but are you sure that `usuario` does indeed have access to create and publish posts?

Comment: yeah, the password and user is correct i check it many many times :S, in fact the user that i use in the code is for the Administrator